# Create a control that has menu's characteristic?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-controls, menu

Can I create a control that has 2 menu's characteristic:

- Do not take form's focus on clicking.
- Automically disappear when clicking outside.

I intend to draw it manually, but I realise I can't draw outside of form's border like system menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the `ToolStripControlHost`, which can contain any control you want.  Paired with the `ToolStripDropDown`, and you have a very effective custom drop down control that will not take focus from the main form, and will close when clicked outside of it:

```
Dim toolDrop As New ToolStripDropDown()
Dim toolHost As New ToolStripControlHost(myControl)
toolHost.Margin = New Padding(0)
toolDrop.Padding = New Padding(0)
toolDrop.Items.Add(toolHost)
toolDrop.Show(Me, New Point(0, 0))
```

Whatever myControl is, sometimes you have to set the MinimumSize of it equal to the size of the control.  There are events you can handle for the ToolStripDropDown such as, `Opening` and `Closing`.

Comment: Thank you it works! Anyway, you're using VB.NET, but I see that the variables names are Java style, lol.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of control? is it a  CommandButton? if so, you can set `Allow Focus` Property to **False**.

Comment: Whose is `AllowFocus` property? I find all UserControl properties but couldn't find that one.